# Integration of Vaadin Charts with Grails. Compiling a widgetset and not able to use charts

Tags: grails, charts, vaadin

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Widgetset compiler" basedir="." default="compile-widgetset">
  <target name="compile-widgetset">
    <path id="classpath">
      <pathelement path="grails-app/vaadin"/>
      <pathelement path="src/java"/>
      <pathelement path="target/classes"/>
      <fileset dir="libs-widgetset">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </path>
    <echo>Compiling ${widgetset}...</echo>
    <property name="module" value="app.AppWidgetSet" />
    <property name="module.output.dir" location="web-app/VAADIN/widgetsets" />
    <property name="localWorkers" value="2" />
    <mkdir dir="${module.output.dir}" />
    <java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" classpathref="classpath" failonerror="yes" fork="yes" maxmemory="512m">
      <arg value="-war" />
      <arg value="${module.output.dir}" />
      <arg value="-localWorkers" />
      <arg value="${localWorkers}" />
      <arg value="-strict" />
      <arg value="${module}" />
      <sysproperty key="vFailIfNotSerializable" value="true" />
      <jvmarg value="-Xss8M" />
      <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256M" />
      <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true" />
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
    <inherits name="org.tepi.filtertable.gwt.FilterTableWidgetset" />
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.charts.Widgetset" />
</module>
```

I am compiling the widgetset and I am getting the following log:-

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\A2\git\aviationlognews\aviationlognew\build.xml
compile-widgetset:
     [echo] Compiling ${widgetset}...
     [java] Compiling module app.AppWidgetSet
     [java]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.vaadin.client.metadata.ConnectorBundleLoader'
     [java]       Rebinding com.vaadin.client.metadata.ConnectorBundleLoader
     [java]          Invoking generator com.vaadin.server.widgetsetutils.ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory
     [java]             Populating eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting ChartOptionsConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ChartOptionsConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.addon.charts.client.ui.ChartOptionsState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.communication.URLReference using URLReference_Serializer
     [java]                Visiting VerticalLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   VerticalLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.orderedlayout.VerticalLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class java.util.HashMap<com.vaadin.shared.Connector, com.vaadin.shared.ui.orderedlayout.AbstractOrderedLayoutState.ChildComponentData> as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.orderedlayout.AbstractOrderedLayoutState.ChildComponentData as a bean
     [java]                Visiting TableConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TableConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.table.TableState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting UIConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   UIConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIState.LoadingIndicatorConfigurationState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIState.LocaleServiceState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIState.TooltipConfigurationState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIState.LocaleData as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize java.lang.String[] as an array
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.PageState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.ui.UIState.PushConfigurationState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.communication.PushMode as an enum
     [java]                Visiting NativeSelectConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   NativeSelectConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.AbstractFieldState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting CustomComponentConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   CustomComponentConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.AbstractComponentState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting PopupButtonConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   PopupButtonConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class org.vaadin.hene.popupbutton.widgetset.client.ui.PopupButtonState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting WindowConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   WindowConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.window.WindowState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.window.WindowMode as an enum
     [java]                Visiting PasswordFieldConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   PasswordFieldConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.textfield.AbstractTextFieldState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting InlineDateFieldConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   InlineDateFieldConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.datefield.InlineDateFieldState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class java.util.Date as a bean
     [java]                Visiting PanelConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   PanelConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.panel.PanelState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting CustomFieldConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   CustomFieldConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting DragAndDropWrapperConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   DragAndDropWrapperConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting LinkConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   LinkConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.link.LinkState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting ImageConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ImageConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.image.ImageState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting BrowserWindowOpenerConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   BrowserWindowOpenerConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.BrowserWindowOpenerState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting LabelConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   LabelConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.LabelState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode as an enum
     [java]                Visiting BrowserFrameConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   BrowserFrameConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.browserframe.BrowserFrameState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting FilterTableConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   FilterTableConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting TreeConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TreeConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.tree.TreeState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting TabsheetConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TabsheetConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.tabsheet.TabsheetState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting NativeButtonConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   NativeButtonConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.NativeButtonState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting PopupDateFieldConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   PopupDateFieldConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.datefield.PopupDateFieldState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting EmbeddedConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   EmbeddedConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.embedded.EmbeddedState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting FlashConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   FlashConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.flash.FlashState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting AudioConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   AudioConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.AbstractMediaState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting CssLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   CssLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.csslayout.CssLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting VideoConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   VideoConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.video.VideoState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting CustomLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   CustomLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.customlayout.CustomLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting FilterTreeTableConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   FilterTreeTableConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.treetable.TreeTableState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting AbsoluteLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   AbsoluteLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.absolutelayout.AbsoluteLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting HorizontalLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   HorizontalLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting TextFieldConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TextFieldConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting ListSelectConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ListSelectConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting FileDownloaderConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   FileDownloaderConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.communication.SharedState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting ButtonConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ButtonConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting GridLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   GridLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.gridlayout.GridLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.gridlayout.GridLayoutState.ChildComponentData as a bean
     [java]                Visiting TwinColSelectConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TwinColSelectConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.twincolselect.TwinColSelectState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting FormConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   FormConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.form.FormState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting JavaScriptExtension with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   JavaScriptExtension will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.JavaScriptExtensionState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting TextAreaConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TextAreaConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.textarea.TextAreaState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting ProgressBarConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ProgressBarConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.progressindicator.ProgressBarState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting UploadConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   UploadConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting FormLayoutConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   FormLayoutConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.orderedlayout.AbstractOrderedLayoutState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting JavaScriptManagerConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   JavaScriptManagerConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.extension.javascriptmanager.JavaScriptManagerState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting ProgressIndicatorConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ProgressIndicatorConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.progressindicator.ProgressIndicatorState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting SliderConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   SliderConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.slider.SliderState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.slider.SliderOrientation as an enum
     [java]                Visiting ComboBoxConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ComboBoxConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.combobox.ComboBoxState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting CheckBoxConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   CheckBoxConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.checkbox.CheckBoxState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting AccordionConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   AccordionConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Visiting VerticalSplitPanelConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   VerticalSplitPanelConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.splitpanel.VerticalSplitPanelState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.splitpanel.AbstractSplitPanelState.SplitterState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting JavaScriptComponentConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   JavaScriptComponentConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.JavaScriptComponentState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting OptionGroupConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   OptionGroupConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.optiongroup.OptionGroupState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting PopupViewConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   PopupViewConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.popupview.PopupViewState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting HorizontalSplitPanelConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   HorizontalSplitPanelConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.splitpanel.HorizontalSplitPanelState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting ChartConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ChartConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.addon.charts.client.ui.ChartState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting MenuBarConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   MenuBarConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.menubar.MenuBarState as a bean
     [java]                Visiting TreeTableConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   TreeTableConnector will be in the eager bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.MouseEventDetails as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.MouseEventDetails.MouseButton as an enum
     [java]             Populating CalendarConnector bundle
     [java]                Visiting CalendarConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   CalendarConnector will be in the CalendarConnector bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.calendar.CalendarState as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.calendar.CalendarState.Action as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.calendar.CalendarState.Day as a bean
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.calendar.CalendarState.Event as a bean
     [java]             Populating RichTextAreaConnector bundle
     [java]                Visiting RichTextAreaConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   RichTextAreaConnector will be in the RichTextAreaConnector bundle
     [java]             Populating ColorPickerGradientConnector bundle
     [java]                Visiting ColorPickerGradientConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ColorPickerGradientConnector will be in the ColorPickerGradientConnector bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.colorpicker.ColorPickerGradientState as a bean
     [java]             Populating ColorPickerAreaConnector bundle
     [java]                Visiting ColorPickerAreaConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ColorPickerAreaConnector will be in the ColorPickerAreaConnector bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.colorpicker.ColorPickerState as a bean
     [java]             Populating ColorPickerConnector bundle
     [java]                Visiting ColorPickerConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ColorPickerConnector will be in the ColorPickerConnector bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.colorpicker.ColorPickerState as a bean
     [java]             Populating ColorPickerGridConnector bundle
     [java]                Visiting ColorPickerGridConnector with ConnectorInitVisitor
     [java]                   ColorPickerGridConnector will be in the ColorPickerGridConnector bundle
     [java]                Will serialize class com.vaadin.shared.ui.colorpicker.ColorPickerGridState as a bean
     [java]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.vaadin.client.ui.dd.VAcceptCriterionFactory'
     [java]       Rebinding com.vaadin.client.ui.dd.VAcceptCriterionFactory
     [java]          Invoking generator com.vaadin.server.widgetsetutils.AcceptCriteriaFactoryGenerator
     [java]             Detecting available criteria ...
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.And
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.AcceptAll
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.AcceptItem
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.ContainsDataFlavor
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.ui.Table.TableDropCriterion
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.TargetItemIs
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.Not
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.TargetDetailIs
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.ui.Tree.TargetInSubtree
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.SourceIs
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.ui.Tree.TreeDropCriterion
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.ServerSideCriterion
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.Or
     [java]             creating mapping for com.vaadin.event.dd.acceptcriteria.SourceIsTarget
     [java]             Done. (0seconds)
     [java]    Compiling 6 permutations
     [java]       Compiling permutation 0...
     [java]       Process output
     [java]          Compiling
     [java]             Compiling permutation 1...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 2...
     [java]          Compiling
     [java]             Compiling permutation 3...
     [java]          Compiling
     [java]             Compiling permutation 4...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 5...
     [java]    Compile of permutations succeeded
     [java] Linking into C:\Users\A2\git\aviationlognews\aviationlognew\web-app\VAADIN\widgetsets\app.AppWidgetSet
     [java]    Link succeeded
     [java]    Compilation succeeded -- 81.581s
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 23 seconds
```

It compiles fine and the Filtertable is working but the charts are not working. It cant find the class. 
I am not able to import the chart class in the View.
Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you mean by "unable to import", that you actually can not do an java/groovy ``import`` to use the class, then there is something wrong with the way you included the charts in your project.  maybe your IDE has not picked your ``BuildConfig.groovy`` after the change?  otherwise: is there an error message you can show us?

Comment: Ya I found the fault is in BuildConfig.groovy
  
It is not accepting this:-
compile 'org.vaadin.addons:vaadin-charts:1.1.6'

Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.vaadin.addons:vaadin-charts:jar:1.1.6 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: you might be missing ``mavenRepo 'http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons'``

Comment: Ant is not bad... but have do you know that you can compile widgetset directly from grails project? https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+on+Grails+-+Widgetset+Compilation